# SQL - Combine two strings having the second string always right aligned

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, alignment

I'm currently trying to attain alignment via SQL queries when combining two columns.

my current data set looks something like:

```
Col1    Col2
usd     US Dollar 
cad     Canadian Dollar 
mxn     Mexican Peso
```

And I want to combine col1 + col2, but no matter how many characters are in col2, the data that comes out of col1 needs to always be aligned to the right in the display.

The display is limited at 49 characters. Col2 has no specific limit as it's a description column, while col1 is a percentage column so it will have a maximum of 7 characters: 100.00%

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where is this being displayed? What are you using to display it?

Comment: I don't understand. Your data set has strings > 7 characters in Col2, but then you say, "col2 is a percentage column so it will have a maximum of 7 characters: 100.00%"

Comment: First, sorry about that. I inadvertently replaced Col1 and Col2 in the explanation and confused things.

Col1 has a maximum of 7 characters
Col2 is variable as it's a description column 

Trying to use select statements to grab my data which will be pulled into excel. problem is i'm limited to arranging the data before it goes to Excel hence why when i'm combining the data from two columns into a single string I need the percentage to always be aligned on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question well and assuming that `col1` has maximal length of 7 characters while `col2` length is undetermined, the following query should give you the results needed:

```
SELECT 
   ISNULL(myTable.col1, '') 
   + (CASE WHEN LEN(ISNULL(myTable.col2, '')) < 49 - LEN(ISNULL(myTable.col1, ''))
           THEN SPACE(49 - LEN(ISNULL(myTable.col1, '')) - LEN(ISNULL(myTable.col2, ''))) 
                + ISNULL(myTable.col2, '')
           ELSE ' ' + LEFT(ISNULL(myTable.col2, ''), 
                           49 - LEN(ISNULL(myTable.col1, '')) - 1)
      END) AS cols_for_49chars_display
FROM
    myTable
```

Since `col1` is assumed to have max length of 7 characters, the `CASE` statement verifies the length of `col2` for specific row.

If it's lower than `49 - LEN(col1)`, prepend `col2` with `49 - LEN(col1) - LEN(col2)` spaces using TSQL `SPACE` function ([docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187950.aspx)) to ***right-align*** `col2` and then add `col2` itself.

In opposite case add one space after `col1` and left-cut `col2` to the length of `49 - LEN(ISNULL(myTable.col1, '')) - 1` when `1` being the length of the added single space character.

### Example input data and results of the query:

Lets take as an example the data provided in your answer adding an extra row to show what will happen when `col2` value is too long:

**`myTable` contents:**

```
col1    col2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
usd     US Dollar
cad     PCanadian Dollar
mxn     Mexican Peso
dummy   Very long description of a "dummy" currency that in fact doesn't exist in the real world
```

The result of the query on above rows would be:

```
           cols_for_49chars_display
-------------------------------------------------
usd                                     US Dollar
cad                              PCanadian Dollar
mxn                                  Mexican Peso
dummy Very long description of a "dummy" currency
```

I hope it helps at least slightly.

Comment: Thanks! - this might look like what I need! - will let you know if this works

* and sorry about the obfuscated way in which I explained it - I just realized I made a complete mess of it :|

Comment: Hi. so I tried the above and indeed the result is always 49 chars in length and the Col1 is always to the right, but because of the characters in col2 and the actual space they occupy on the screen it's not a perfect 'visual' alignment.
Even so I marked the answer as correct because at the basis of it the result was correct. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it helped you at least a little. **Please find the EDITED** part at the end of my answer - would such display be OK for your needs? I think it might be possible to achieve it while still having maximum of 49 chars.

Comment: Thanks. I indeed took that into consideration as it would be way easier, but unfortunately it's up to the client that will be using the report and they don't seem to flexible. Appreciate the thought though.

Comment: No problem. Thx also for your replies :)